# Error "str.replace is not a function" when using store.queryRecord with Ember Octane

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, ember-octane

I'm following an [Embercasts](https://embercasts.com) course (Ember + Rails). For the screencasts, they used Ember 3.0, but I'm using Octane.

In one video, a custom service is implemented. This is what my version looks like:

```
import Service, { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class CurrentUserService extends Service {
  @service store;

  load() {
    this.store.queryRecord('user', { me: true })
      .then((user) => {
        this.set('user', user);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        debugger;
      });
  }
}
```

In the `load` function, which is being called from a route, `this.store.queryRecord()` causes an error:

```
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
  at Cache.func (index.js:64)
  at Cache.get (index.js:774)
  at decamelize (index.js:167) 
  at Cache.func (index.js:32)
  at Cache.get (index.js:774)
  at Object.dasherize (index.js:190)
  at UserAdapter.pathForType (json-api.js:221)
  at UserAdapter._buildURL (-private.js:293)
  at UserAdapter.buildURL (-private.js:275)
  at UserAdapter.urlForQueryRecord (user.js:13)
```

The relevant line is

```
var DECAMELIZE_CACHE = new _utils.Cache(1000, str => str.replace(STRING_DECAMELIZE_REGEXP, '$1_$2').toLowerCase());
```

This is the `UserAdapter`:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default class UserAdapter extends ApplicationAdapter {
  urlForQueryRecord(query) {
    if (query.me) {
      delete query.me;

      return `${super.buildURL(...arguments)}/me`;
    }

    return `${super.buildURL(...arguments)}`;
  }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: how does your adapter look like? I assume `str` is not a string.

Comment: Yes, `str` is undefined. I added the `UserAdapter` to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `super.buildURL(...arguments)` you essentially do `super.buildURL(query)`. And `query` is an object (`{ me: true }`) not a string while `buildURL` expects the `modelName` as first parameter.

So probably you wanna do something like this instead:

```
urlForQueryRecord(query, modelName) {
  if (query.me) {
    delete query.me;

    return `${super.buildURL(modelName)}/me`;
  }

  return `${super.buildURL(modelName)}`;
}
```